# TypeScript enum from JSON file nested array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a JSON config file in my project like this:

```
{
  "countries": {
    "ca": [
      "en-CA",
      "fr-CA"
    ],
    "us": [
      "en-US"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to create a TS enum for all locales, something like:

```
import config from './config.json'

const locales = Object.values(config.countries).map(locales => locales).flat()

type Locales = typeof locales
```

However, this (or anything similar) does not work, because TS isn't aware of the actual values of `config.countries[0]` – it just denotes them as `string` or `string[]`.

Is this type of thing possible, or do we need to manually maintain duplication?

Comment: Does this solve your problem or you still need more info?

Comment: `.map(locales => locales)` is pointless

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate enums dynamically but you can specify that the object is a const so you can copy paste the types from your code when you hover over your `const locales`. simply add:

```
const config = {
  countries: {
    ca: ["en-CA", "fr-CA"],
    us: ["en-US"]
  }
} as const; <---------- this guy

const locales = Object.values(config.countries).flat();
```

This way at least you have something to copy

[image]

But I would be lying if I said you can't generate enum from code. It's just that you need a little bit of mindset change.

You can always imagine parts of your code to be dependent on a single source of truth. And then have a code generation step after you install your dependencies (This will save you writing ton of boilerplate and repetition in larger projects).

Then add some script that read specific files and produce typescript for your project. The best library to do this with is [ts-morph](https://ts-morph.com/) which gives nice syntactic sugar on top of TypeScript Compiler API.

I gave examples similar (Reverse to your question) to this on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170471/get-values-of-union-elements-in-typescript/61173522#61173522).